# Stomp gives TCP connection failure and disconnection error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have been using STOMP and sockjs for some time now, but the error below happens at times.

```
12:57:30.976 [48] [tcp-client-loop-nio-4] INFO  org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - TCP connection failure in session w6s21o5d: failed to forward DISCONNECT session=w6s21o5d
reactor.netty.channel.AbortedException: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
  at reactor.netty.FutureMono$FutureSubscription.wrapError(FutureMono.java:186) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar!/:1.0.7]
  at reactor.netty.FutureMono$FutureSubscription.operationComplete(FutureMono.java:177) [reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar!/:1.0.7]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetFailure(AbstractChannel.java:1021) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:882) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1367) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:709) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:792) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:702) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:304) [netty-handler-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1071) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497) [netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
```

The disconnection message is send from frontend as shown below before page reload.

```
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
        client.disconnect(function () {
            log("disconnect websocket..");
        });
    });
```

No logic is written in backend to handle this spring-stomp handles rest of it.

I have gone through resources in STOMP and there is still no explanation on why or exactly on what scenarios this is happening. What could be the possible reasons for this error.

Comment: FWIW, STOMP is just a protocol. It doesn't "give" TCP connection failures or disconnection errors. The server which implements STOMP does that.

Comment: More information is needed. Code block or sample code of server side implementation

Comment: You send Disconnect but channel is already closed.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez Disconnect is send from the frontend side right?

Comment: yes it seems so

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez if that's the case how does it cause error in the backend? Where is disconnection being forwarded to?

Comment: When you send Disconnect and you get Disconnect logic from backend. If you immediately closes socket no response will  be given and throws exception like in example. How are you closing your socket? can you send detail?

Comment: @JustinBertram I have added more details to this question. Do you see any reason why this would be happening?

Comment: IMHO it is related to server side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243288/discussion-between-pacman-and-gurkan-lleez).